# how to implement oracle -> oracle conversion/refresher program in C# / ADO.NET 2.0

Tags: c#, ado.net

When program runs 1st time it just gets some fields from a source database table say:

```
SELECT NUMBER, COLOR, USETYPE, ROOFMATERIALCODE FROM HOUSE;  //number is uniq key
```

it does some in-memory processing say converting USETYPE and ROOFMATERIAL to destination database format (by using cross ref table).

Then program inserts ALL THE ROWS to destination database:

```
INSERT INTO BUILDING (BUILDINGID, BUILDINGNUMBER, COLOR, BUILDINGTYPE, ROOFMAT) 
VALUES (PROGRAM_GENERATED_ID, NUMBER_FROM_HOUSE, COLOR_FROM_HOUSE, 
CONVERTED_USETYPE_FROM_HOUSE, CONVERTED_ROOFMATERIALCODE_FROM_HOUSE);
```

The above is naturally not SQL but you get the idea (the values with underscores just describe the data inserted).

The next times the program should do the same except:

1. insert only the ones not found from target database.
2. update only the ones that have updated color, usetype, roofmaterialcode.

My question is:

1. How to implement this in efficient way? 
   -Do I first populate DataSet and convert fields to destination format?
   -If I use only 1 DataSet how give destination db BUILDING_IDs (can i add columns to   populated DataSet?)
   -How to efficiently check if destination rows need refresh (if i select them one @ time by BUILDING_NUMBER and check all fields it's gonna be slow)?

Thanks for your answers!

-matti

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Oracle, have you looked at the MERGE statement?  You give the merge statement a criteria.  If records match the criteria, it performs an UPDATE.  If they don't match the criteria (they aren't already in the table), it performs an INSERT.  That might be helpful for what you are trying to do.

[Here](http://www.psoug.org/reference/merge.html) is the spec/example of merge.

Comment: i think i create 2 DataSets. target DataSet is populated from target database (1st time empty). source DataSet is populated from source db. when the changes are somehow merged to target DataSet it's simply written to target db by calling AcceptChanges. this approach has serious drawback though. it requires huge amount of memory.

Comment: Yeah, if you use the MERGE statement and execute that directly against the database, you can get rid of your ADO DataSets and not use any client memory.